# Change string - to capitalize letter

Tags: php, string

Is it possible to edit a string like `Text-element` to `TextElement`? After each - it needs an capital letter.

I can't get it done and can't figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
$text = implode(array_map('ucfirst',explode('-',$str)));
```

First we split all string at point of hyphen `-` and then each of the first letter would be in caps. Then, join it back.

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/150008)**

Answer (score 3):

```
$text = preg_replace_callback(
    '/-([a-z])/',
    function (array $match) { return strtoupper($match[1]); },
    $text
);
```

Comment: Yay [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback)! One of my favourite functions...

Comment: Slight variation: `preg_replace_callback('/([a-z]+)-?/', function ($m) { return ucfirst($m[1]); }, strtolower($str));`

Comment: @Amal Yeah, depends on what exactly the OP is looking for...

Comment: No answer would correctly convert `a-b3-3`. I suggest `/(?:^|-)(.)/`.

Comment: @meze: What would be the result in that case? `AB3-3`? (Since you can't capitalize a number.)

Comment: @AmalMurali The OP needs to answer that. It was only a note

Answer (score 0):

This shoudl do it ...

```
$string = "Text-element";
$s = explode("-", $string);
$finished_string = $s[0] . ucfirst($s[1]);
```

Comment: Can anyone at least explain why this is downvoted like this? It works perfectly, buhu, i use 3 lines of code and not some cool preg_replace_callback functions. Im a bad human.

Comment: It would only work with "two word" strings, additional words would be cut off. I didn't downvote though ;)

Comment: No idea why this got downvoted, even if it's for a single case, it still works. +1.

Comment: Dont get me wrong, i have no problems with downvoting, it tells me that i did something wrong. But just downvoting without saying something like "Hey, you are a stupid idiot because of ..." is not helping me. ;(

Comment: That works fine , My contribution to you mate.